# spark java core - Is there a connection timeout default on server side for routes, if so can we override it?

Tags: spark-java

I am trying to set the connection timeout for the spark server plain version as i want it to be inline with Client connection timeout, meaning if client times out the server request should not proceed in the server end.

I am using spark-core com.sparkjava maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried using threadPool to override idletimeout but that doesn't had any effect on my server - https://sparkjava.com/documentation#embedded-web-server

There is feature in Apache spark to override the connection idle timeout, but i don't see any such in com.sparkjava spark-core.

Is there any other way to know / understand what is the default timeout of connection in spark server ? Is there any way to override that timeout ?

Note: I am not using any WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue before, and it turned out that the problem was not with the framework itself but with the Nginx configuration.
I suggest checking your Nginx configuration settings as it might be causing the connection timeout.
I suggest testing it on your local machine. If the issue stops, it may be a reverse proxy problem.

Best